# Alamofire 3->4 trouble with Reponse & ResponseSerializer Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, alamofire, swift3

I'm having trouble with the ResponseSerializer I get an unresolved identifier and for Response I get an undeclared type. I've read from [alamofire migration doc](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) that Response has been changed to multiple types. So I should change Response->DataReponse but this means I can only pass one argument like:

```
// What I have
Response(<ListWrapper, NSError>)

// What I should change it to?
DataResponse(<ListWrapper>)
```

How can I still recieve the Error this way and more importantly how do I migrate the extension to alamofire 4?

**My class:**

```
class List{

    var idNumber: String?
    var title: String?
    var posterPath: String?
    var release: String?

    required init(json: JSON, id: Int?) 
    {
        self.idNumber = json[ListFields.Id.rawValue].stringValue
        self.title = json[ListFields.Title.rawValue].stringValue
        self.posterPath = json[ListFields.PosterPath.rawValue].stringValue
        self.release = json[ListFields.Release.rawValue].stringValue
    }

    class func setURL_APPEND(_ url: String)
    {
        URL_APPEND  = url
    }

    // MARK: Endpoints
    class func endpointForList() -> String 
    {
        return URL_APPEND
    }


    fileprivate class func getListAtPath(_ path: String, completionHandler: @escaping (ListWrapper?, NSError?) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(path)
            .responseListArray { response in

                if let error = response.result.error
                {
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                completionHandler(response.result.value, nil)
        }
    }

    class func getList(_ completionHandler: @escaping (ListWrapper?, NSError?) -> Void) 
    {
        getListAtPath(List.endpointForList(), completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }


}
// Problem is here:
// for ResponseSerializer I get an unresolved identifier 
// and for Response I get an undeclared type
extension Alamofire.Request {
    func responseListArray(_ completionHandler: @escaping (Response<ListWrapper, NSError>) -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<ListWrapper, NSError> { request, response, data, error in

            guard error == nil else 
            {
                return .failure(error!)
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                let failureReason = "Array could not be serialized because input data was nil."
                let error = Alamofire.Error.errorWithCode(.dataSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                return .failure(error)
            }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

            switch result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = SwiftyJSON3.JSON(value)
                let wrapper = ListWrapper()

                var allList:Array = Array<List>()

                wrapper.totalCount = json["favorite_count"].intValue

                // print(json)
                let results = json["items"]
                // print(results)
                for jsonList in results
                {
                    //print(jsonList.1)

                    let list = List(json: jsonList.1, id: Int(jsonList.0) )
                    if (list.posterPath == "")
                    {
                        continue
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //print(movies.posterPath)
                        allList.append(list)
                    }

                }
                wrapper.results = allList
                return .success(wrapper)
            case .failure(let error):
                return .failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer,completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bro try below code see:

```
func responseListArray(_ completionHandler: @escaping (Response<ListWrapper>) -> Void) -> Self {
    let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<ListWrapper> { request, response, data, error in

        guard error == nil else 
        {
            return .failure(error!)
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
             return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputDataNil))

        }

        let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
        let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

        switch result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = SwiftyJSON3.JSON(value)
            let wrapper = ListWrapper()

            var allList:Array = Array<List>()

            wrapper.totalCount = json["favorite_count"].intValue

            // print(json)
            let results = json["items"]
            // print(results)
            for jsonList in results
            {
                //print(jsonList.1)

                let list = List(json: jsonList.1, id: Int(jsonList.0) )
                if (list.posterPath == "")
                {
                    continue
                }
                else
                {
                    //print(movies.posterPath)
                    allList.append(list)
                }

            }
            wrapper.results = allList
            return .success(wrapper)
        case .failure(let error):
            return .failure(error)
        }
    }

    return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer,completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a error at the last return statement "Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'"?

Comment: change to extension Alamofire.DataRequest ?
Same issue?

Comment: Yes already tried that didn't work. Response & ResponseSerializer aren't recognized. So shouldn't I change them into DataResponse & DataResponseSerializer as well?

Comment: Yea change it to DataResponse & DataResponseSerializer. How is it now

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @StefanLam  could you please please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838682/alamofire4-trouble-with-jsonresponseserializer-httpurlresponse-swift-3-0 I have the exact same problem but I dont understand from reading you guys comments

Comment: @Mat0 could you please please have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838682/alamofire4-trouble-with-jsonresponseserializer-httpurlresponse-swift-3-0 I have the exact same problem but I dont understand from reading you guys comments