# Alamofire4 trouble with JSONResponseSerializer & HTTPURLResponse Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

Since I updated Alamofire I get the errors: **Type Request has no member JSONResponseSerializer** and **cannot call value of non-function type HTTPURLResponse**

I have already switched Response to DataResponse but I still get the error.

[image]

Code:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    func responseUserEventsArray(_ completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<UserEventsWrapper>) -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = DataResponseSerializer<UserEventsWrapper> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else
            {
                return .failure(error!)
            }
            guard let responseData = data else {
                return .failure(AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: .inputDataNil))

            }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .allowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, responseData, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                let wrapper = UserEventsWrapper()

                wrapper.next = json["eventhistory"]["next_page_url"].stringValue
                wrapper.previous = json["eventhistory"]["prev_page_url"].stringValue
                wrapper.count = json["eventhistory"]["total"].intValue

                var allUserEvents:Array = Array<UserEvents>()
                print(json)
                let results = json["eventhistory"]["data"]
                print(results)

                for jsonAds in results
                {
                    print(jsonAds.1)
                    let adsData = UserEvents(json: jsonAds.1, id: Int(jsonAds.0))
                    allUserEvents.append(adsData)
                }
                wrapper.usereventsitems = allUserEvents
                return .success(wrapper)
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer,completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED

---

Change

`Request.JSONResponseSerializer` to `DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer`

`extension Alamofire.Request` to `extension Alamofire.DataRequest` – Mat0

`.success` and `.failure` - FranMowinckel

Comment: And extension Alamofire.Request to extension Alamofire.DataRequest

Comment: And .success and .failure

Comment: Thanks for helping me out again! I will accept when it unlocks :)